# Is there an equivalent for SQL Server's @@error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling

I want to run an update query against a production database and as good little developer I am trying to make it as safe as possible. I am looking to do the following

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE table_x SET col_y = 'some_value'
    .
    .
    .
IF (@@error <> 0)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    COMMIT
END
```

The above should work in SQL Server but I need this to work against a MySQL database.

EDIT:
Sorry, there is more than 1 statement to execute. Yes I am aware of not needing to wrap a single query in a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is necessary as there is the concept of implicit commit/rollback.

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-implicit-commit.html):

> By default, MySQL starts the session
>   for each new connection with
>   autocommit mode enabled, so MySQL does
>   a commit after each SQL statement if
>   that statement did not return an
>   error. If a statement returns an
>   error, the commit or rollback behavior
>   depends on the error. See Section
>   13.6.13, “InnoDB Error Handling”.

Comment: Although the ROLLBACK would also roll back any outer, nested, transactions (in MSSQL at least).  I think OP was after the MySQL detection method equivalent to @@ERROR in MSSQL, and this may just be a Noddy example

Comment: I'll interpret what Assaf is saying by saying this: As an MSSQL developer, think of MySQL as having SET XACT_ABORT ON by default. I wasn't familiar with this setting until recently. Check out this site:
http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/set-set_40.htm

Comment: For anyone who needs it, the docs have been moved here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-error-handling.html

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE foo SET bar = 3;
UPDATE bar SET thing = 5;
COMMIT;
```

If an error occurs, the entire transaction will be rolled back automatically. You really only need to execute `ROLLBACK` if something in your application indicates the need to rollback.

---

It is possible to handle errors explicitly within procedures or compound statements in MySQL, but I wouldn't recommend going down this route. See this [how-to article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3554616/MySQL-Stored-Procedures-Part-3.htm) and the [docs for DECLARE HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html). You'll also have to [find the specific error code you want to handle](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html), or you can use the general `SQLEXCEPTION` condition. You'll also want to review [compound statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/begin-end.html) and [defining stored programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Anyway, based on the docs, you could do something like the query below, but it honestly wouldn't do anything differently than my previous answer above. It would also get you *very strange* looks from anyone who uses MySQL (including myself).

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
  START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE foo SET bar = 3;
    UPDATE bar SET thing = 5;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

---

Old answer:

If you're executing a single query, this doesn't make sense. Simply execute the query; if an error occurs, nothing will happen - your transaction will automatically be rolled back.

The reason is that, by default, all single queries are wrapped in a "hidden" transaction, called "autocommit" mode in MySQL. The typical alternative is to explicitly use transactions - once you execute "BEGIN" you have started a transaction. Once you either COMMIT or ROLLBACK you'll be back in autocommit mode.

So, the only reason to use a transaction in MySQL is if you want to rollback to a particular state when an error (or some other external event) occurs. In MySQL, a transaction is always aborted if an error occurs.

Lastly, it is possible to turn this behavior off entirely, and then you must use transactions explicitly at all times. I believe "BEGIN" is implied from when you last committed or rolled back, but you must either COMMIT or ROLLBACK any queries you run.

See [The InnoDB Transaction Model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) in the MySQL manual for more info.

Comment: Just curious (me=MSSQL): are there any errors in MySQL which would not cause a rollback? DeadLock? I'm trying to think of one in MSSQL, only thing I can think of is an EXEC of a nested Stored Procedure that could have failed, but the rest of code in outer SProc will run if no error handling.

Comment: In time, deadlocks time out, return errors and rollback; threads (queries) that are manually killed have the same effect; etc. Any case where the rollback didn't happen I would have to think is a bug. I've never seen anything to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
  END;
  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT
    INTO t_test VALUES ('test', 'test');
    INSERT
    INTO no_such_table
    VALUES ('no');
  COMMIT;
END;

CALL prc_test();

SELECT *
FROM t_test;

0 rows fetched.
```