# Mysql transaction error message

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

I have a typical transaction of

```
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO ...
UPDATE ...
DELETE ...
COMMIT
```

**Problem 1:** Failure in `UPDATE` will not block the transaction. In single query, I use `mysql_affected_rows()` to inspect the success of `UPDATE` but how to do so in the middle of a Transaction?

**Problem 2:** How to detect which query caused the transaction stop? To make a if condiction in `PHP`?

Comment: See this example: [Transaction with Stored Procedure in MySQL Server](http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/transaction-with-stored-procedure-in-mysql-server/)

Comment: Or this example by @Quassnoi: [EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552628/is-there-an-equivalent-for-sql-servers-error-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `mysql_*()` functions based on your mention of `mysql_affected_rows()`, you should simply be calling each stage of the transaction in its own `mysql_query()` and checking its success or failure at each stage. Unless you wrap this as a stored procedure, you have to call these as individual statements since `mysql_query()` doesn't support multiple statements in one call.

```
function doTransaction() {
  mysql_query("START TRANSACTION;");
  $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ....");
  if (!$ins) {
    // fail
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    return FALSE;
  }

  $upd = mysql_query("UPDATE...");
  if (!$upd) {
    // fail
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    return FALSE;  
  }
  if (mysql_affected rows() === 0) {
    // no rows updated, rollback if necessary
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    return FALSE;
  }

  $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM...");
  if (!$del) {
    // fail
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    return FALSE;
  }

  // All succeeded
  mysql_query("COMMIT");
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: very clever trick to mix put mysql queries inside php if statements!

Comment: @Ali Not so much clever, as a standard practice. See [the mysql_* docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for examples.