# 2 SQL Statements: 1 invalid, 1 valid, does the valid one get executed?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Say for example I have this MySQL statement:

```
select somefield from table where otherfield='some')%$#@%; insert into table.....
```

Will the insert statement get executed even if the first statement throws an error?

Comment: Can you try it out and see the result?

Comment: I don't have access to a sql server at the moment, I'm just curious.

Comment: I also don't know of any SQL simulators that will simulate MySQL's exact behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, there is a concept called XACT_ABORT which when set to ON, causes the server to abort the entire batch whenever an error occurs.  My SQL has this feature built in.

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552628/is-there-an-equivalent-for-sql-servers-error-in-mysql)

From [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-implicit-commit.html),

> By default, MySQL starts the session for each new connection with
>   autocommit mode enabled, so MySQL does a commit after each SQL
>   statement if that statement did not return an error. If a statement
>   returns an error, the commit or rollback behavior depends on the
>   error. See Section 13.6.13, “InnoDB Error Handling”.