# Replica of SqlServer @@Error in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

What's the equivalent of the MSSQL variable `@@ERROR` in MySQL?
I have one line in stored proc like below:

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552628/is-there-an-equivalent-for-sql-servers-error-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You use [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html) or, better still, set an [error handler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html). See [MySQL Stored Procedure Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764887/mysql-stored-procedure-error-handling).