# @@error in sql server , what alternate into Mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

> @@Error :this for exception handling into sql server.but i have no
>   idea into Mysql server.
>
> So Anybody please help on this,
>
> i shall be thankful to you.

**For Example**

**sql server** Code like this

```
If (@@error <> 0)
     Begin
      Raiserror (50002, 11, 1)
      Rollback transaction
      goto Bailout
   End
```

**Mysql code**

```
 If @@error <> 0    # getting Error 
   Then
     Signal  SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 50084
     Rollback;     #getting Error
   End if;
```

> i just want to convert sql server code to mysql server code.

Thanks
Aman

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552628/is-there-an-equivalent-for-sql-servers-error-in-mysql

Comment: @ Abhishek : Thanks for reply, this link is related to the Store Proc. , Mysql Store Proc is handle the TRANSACTION but Mysql Trigger is not.